# Unable to get fields from INVENTORYALLOCATIONS while I do not need any fields from ALLLEDGERENTRIES while making xml request to Tally

Tags: tally

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>CA_VOUCHER</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:xml</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Company Name</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">07-03-2023</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">07-03-2023</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FORM>CA_VOUCHER</FORM>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <PART>CA_VOUCHER</PART>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERS</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHER</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHER:CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER:ALLLEDGERENTRIES</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY:INVENTORYALLOCATIONS</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FIELDS>
                            CA_DATE,CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME,CA_VOUCHERNUMBER</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHER</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER:Yes</EXPLODE>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                        <FIELDS>CA_LEDGERNAME</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>ENTRY</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY:Yes</EXPLODE>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY">
                        <FIELDS>CA_STOCKITEMNAME,CA_ACTUALQTY,CA_RATE</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>STOCKITEM</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_DATE">
                        <TYPE>Date</TYPE>
                        <SET>$Date</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>DATE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME">
                        <SET>$VOUCHERTYPENAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERTYPE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERNUMBER">
                        <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERNUMBER</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_LEDGERNAME">
                        <SET>$LEDGERNAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>LEDGER</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_STOCKITEMNAME">
                        <SET>$STOCKITEMNAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>NAME</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_ACTUALQTY">
                        <TYPE>Quantity</TYPE>
                        <SET>$ACTUALQTY</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>QUANTITY</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_RATE">
                        <TYPE>Rate</TYPE>
                        <SET>$RATE</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>RATE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION">
                        <TYPE> Vouchers : VoucherType</TYPE>
                        <CHILDOF>$$VchTypeSales</CHILDOF>
                        <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Abode code is working fine but neither I need any ledger name nor I need my inventory items enclosed in Entry element (ALLLEDGERENTRIES). When I send request with following XML body it  throw fatal error and closed tally.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>CA_VOUCHER</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:xml</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Company Name</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">07-03-2023</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">07-03-2023</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FORM>CA_VOUCHER</FORM>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <PART>CA_VOUCHER</PART>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERS</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHER</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHER:CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER:ALLLEDGERENTRIES</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY:INVENTORYALLOCATIONS</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FIELDS>
                            CA_DATE,CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME,CA_VOUCHERNUMBER</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHER</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGER:Yes</EXPLODE>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                        <FIELDS></FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>ENTRY</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY:Yes</EXPLODE>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY">
                        <FIELDS>CA_STOCKITEMNAME,CA_ACTUALQTY,CA_RATE</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>STOCKITEM</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_DATE">
                        <TYPE>Date</TYPE>
                        <SET>$Date</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>DATE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME">
                        <SET>$VOUCHERTYPENAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERTYPE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERNUMBER">
                        <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERNUMBER</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_STOCKITEMNAME">
                        <SET>$STOCKITEMNAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>NAME</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_ACTUALQTY">
                        <TYPE>Quantity</TYPE>
                        <SET>$ACTUALQTY</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>QUANTITY</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_RATE">
                        <TYPE>Rate</TYPE>
                        <SET>$RATE</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>RATE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION">
                        <TYPE> Vouchers : VoucherType</TYPE>
                        <CHILDOF>$$VchTypeSales</CHILDOF>
                        <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I want to generate the following response with above mentioned xml request body.

```
<VOUCHERS>
    <VOUCHER>
        <DATE>1-Feb-23</DATE>
        <VOUCHERTYPE>Sales</VOUCHERTYPE>
        <VOUCHERNUMBER>1</VOUCHERNUMBER>
        <STOCKITEM>
            <NAME>Product Name</NAME>
            <QUANTITY>1000 Pcs</QUANTITY>
            <RATE>1.50/Pcs</RATE>
        </STOCKITEM>
    </VOUCHER> 
    *
    * 
    * 
</VOUCHERS>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Some **indentation** to make the structure of the XML obvious would go a loooooong way!

Comment: First xml is working fine, you will get stock item data but it's in different format.

Comment: Yes, first xml is perfectly working but I am also getting Ledger Name (CA_LEDGERNAME) which I do not need, the last format is my desired format. But I am not getting inventory items and even it throws error and quit tally if I remove CA_LEDGERNAME.

Comment: From the child nodes of ALLLEDGERENTRIES, I need only INVENTORYALLOCATIONS and its sub nodes (StockName, Qty, Rate and Amount). So that is why I am removing LedgerName node which is direct descendent of AllLedgerEntries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second xml CA_VOUCHERLEDGER line has no fields, so tally throws error
instead change to

```
<LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                        <FIELDS>SimpleField</FIELDS>
                        <EXPLODE>CA_VOUCHERLEDGERINVENTORY:Yes</EXPLODE>
                        <LOCAL>Delete:FIELD:SimpleField</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
```

you will get empty `<SIMPLEFIELD></SIMPLEFIELD>` tags you can ignore while parsing
[image]

Comment: If yoy see CA_VOUCHERLEDGER line provided by me , I removed xmltag,
if think you kept as is

Comment: Yes I saw later, that worked thank you very much